# Safari web inspector breaks media queries

Tags: safari, web-inspector

Using Safari Version 11.1, whenever I open the web inspector on a web page, all media queries in the CSS stop working. If I close the inspector, the problem goes away. This happens on any site.

Are other people experiencing this? Is there a setting that I've toggled?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you enabled "Force Print Media Styles" (a small printer icon in the upper right corner under the Elements tab):
[image: Force Print Media Styles]

Comment: Oh my, you saved my life!! Thanks so much, I would never have spotted that.

Answer (score 1):

I also have experienced this problem. After doing some research I finally manage to solve the problem.

Backup and remove ~/Library/WebKit/com.apple.Safari folder.

A problem should disappear after that operation. Enjoy :D